# Repentance for stealing not accepted?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, repentance-teshuvah, gezel-stealing, bava-kamma

I've heard before that there is a Gemorah in Baba Kamma (also brought down in Shulchan Aruch Choshen Mishpat Hilchos Genevah) that one who steals something and later wishes to repent and return what was stolen, we don't always accept it from him (for whatever reason.)

Is there such a gemorah or halacha in Shulchan Aruch? If so what is the reason? Do we accept this? Would there be any exceptions to this rule for someone that stole and now wants to return what he stole?

Comment: Bava Kama 94b ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 5):

What you are referring to is תקנת השבים - Takanat-Hashavim - a special dispensation for those who repent.

By the strict letter of the law, you have to return what you stole. If it no longer exits, then you have to pay for it.

However, since it would be a more inconvenience to return certain items, Chazal declared that the thief may keep those items and pay for them instead.

The typical example is a stolen beam that has been used to build a house. By the strict letter of the law, you have to return that beam, even if it means destroying your house. Since this would prevent many a thief from doing Teshuva, Chazal declared that the thief may keep the beam, and pay for it instead.

As the Rambam says in [הלכות גזילה ואבידה פרק א](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/b301.htm):

> ד:   כל הגוזל--חייב להחזיר הגזילה עצמה, שנאמר "והשיב את הגזילה אשר גזל" (ויקרא ה,כג).  ואם אבדה או נשתנת, משלם דמיה:  בין שהודה מפי עצמו, בין שבאו עליו עדים שגזל--הרי זה חייב לשלם הקרן בלבד.
>   אפילו גזל קורה, ובנה אותה בבירה, הואיל ולא נשתנת, דין תורה הוא שיהרוס את כל הבניין ויחזיר קורה לבעליה; אבל תיקנו חכמים מפני תקנת השבים, שיהיה נותן את דמיה ולא יפסיד הבניין.  וכן כל כיוצא בזה.

Sometimes, Chazal declared that one should not even accept the repayment - even if it's being offered - in order to facilitate the Teshuva. If the item no longer exists or the person wants to do teshuva for lending with Ribis, then one should refrain from accepting the money.

As codified by the Rambam, ibid:

> יג:  כל הגוזל את חברו שווה פרוטה--כאילו נטל נשמתו ממנו, שנאמר "כן--אורחות, כל בוצע בצע; את נפש בעליו, ייקח" (משלי א,יט).  ואף על פי כן, אם לא הייתה הגזילה קיימת, ורצה הגזלן לעשות תשובה, ובא מאליו והחזיר דמי הגזילה--תקנת חכמים היא שאין מקבלין ממנו, אלא עוזרין אותו ומוחלין לו כדי לקרב הדרך הישרה על השבים.  וכל המקבל ממנו דמי הגזילה, אין רוח חכמים נוחה הימנו.

And again in [הלכות מלווה ולווה פרק ד](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/d304.htm)

> ח:   הגזלנין ומלווי בריבית שהחזירו--אין מקבלין מהן, כדי לפתוח להן דרך לתשובה; וכל המקבל מהן, אין רוח חכמים נוחה הימנו.  ואם הייתה הגזילה קיימת, והריבית דבר מסויים, והרי הוא בעצמו--מקבלין מהן.

Sources:

- [:מסכת בבא קמא דף צד](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37963&st=&pgnum=199&hilite=)
- Rambam, as cited above
- Shulchan Aruch: Choshen Hamishpat 366:1 and Yoreh De'ah 161:7